# gwt label click handler problem

Tags: java, gwt, onclick, label

I am getting an error when clicking on a label, the label has a
click handler attached to it, i am using GWT 2.1 and the problem is
only on IE

stack trace:

```
09:27:45.777 [ERROR] [biddingsystem] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions
caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:
214)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:
103)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:
96)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:107)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:
116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:
155)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:
157)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:
326)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:
207)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:
126)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:
561)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:
269)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:
91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:
157)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:
281)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:
531)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:
352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more
exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:
214)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:
103)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:
96)
    at com.BiddingSystem.client.Presenter.SigninRegisterPresenter
$1.onClick(SigninRegisterPresenter.java:50)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:
54)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:
204)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:
103)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:
96)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:107)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:
116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:
155)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:
157)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:
326)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:
207)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:
126)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:
561)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:
269)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:
91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:
157)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:
281)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:
531)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:
352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error):
Invalid argument.
 number: -2147024809
 description: Invalid argument.
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:
237)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:
126)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:
561)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:
289)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:
107)
    at com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element$.setPropertyInt$
(Element.java)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.setElementPropertyInt(DOM.java:
1118)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable
$FlexCellFormatter.setColSpan(FlexTable.java:78)
    at com.BiddingSystem.client.View.LoginView.<init>(LoginView.java:
61)
    at com.BiddingSystem.client.ApplicationController
$1.onSignIn(ApplicationController.java:110)
    at
com.BiddingSystem.client.event.SignInEvent.dispatch(SignInEvent.java:
18)
    at
com.BiddingSystem.client.event.SignInEvent.dispatch(SignInEvent.java:
1)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:
204)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:
103)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:
96)
    at com.BiddingSystem.client.Presenter.SigninRegisterPresenter
$1.onClick(SigninRegisterPresenter.java:50)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:
54)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:
204)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:
103)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:
96)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:107)
    at
com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:
116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:
155)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:
157)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:
326)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:
207)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:
126)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:
561)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:
269)
    at
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:
91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Comment: It look to me your cause is right there in your stack trace and has nothing to do with label or clickhandlers, but with setting colspan.

Comment: Could you add your code? Especially Line 50 in SigninRegisterPresenter.java

Comment: @ykartal: I just want to know 1 thing, in gwt we work on a single code base, ok, i.e. we never consider browser incompatibilities because this is upto gwt to handle through differed binding, but how is it that on Firefox and chrome  everthing is OK, but the problem is only on Internet Explorer

Comment: This is not happening only for signinregister but everywhere in my app where I am attaching a click handler on a label. Other are saying that it does not make sence to add a click handler to a label, but in gwt, a label HAS a click handler, thus we should be able to use it!!

Comment: If it is working only in IE and working in all browsers means you can try in other versions of IE. If you find the problem with only specific version of IE then you can inform microsoft team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `*.gwt.xml` files.
And delete below line all of them

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="..anything.." />
```

Add below line to `project_name.gwt.xml`

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
```

Then try in Internet Explorer instead of Firefox, etc.

If still not works, try this code;

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label = new com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label("asdasd");
        l.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MessageBox.info("", "asd", null);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HTML instead of Label. Actually if you want a "clickable" component, Button or HTML with hyperlink or Anchor or Hyperlink would make more sense as they are more intuitive to the user.

Comment: Label click handler works, no need to use an alternative for Label